# (Relative) amounts of visible polygon areas? (Geo features in OpenLayers)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, openlayers, area

In an OpenLayers map with geo features (country borders, so complex polygons), I want to determine what the user is primarily looking at.

Basing this "importance" calculation on center points is not a good idea IMO, as it could easily fail for a lot of country borders that come to mind.

Instead, I would like to calculate a rough approximation of the visible areas, or relative values of how the visible areas relate.

[image: Relative area amounts]

Is there any faster way than to cut out the visible polygon areas (using the viewport bounds) and do a precise calculation of the visible area? A possible JavaScript solution is supposed to run at clientside, so it shouldn't be an expansive and exact algorithm.

I don't want to use reverse lookups to get close-by country names, just if you wondered.

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenLayers `map.getExtent` you can determine the bounding box of the current viewport.
Then simply loop through your polygons to determine which intersect with that viewport.

```
var mapExtent = map.getExtent().toGeometry();
var featuresOnScreen = [];
for (var i = 0, i < myFeatures.features.length;; i+=1) {
    var poly = myFeatures.features[i];
    if (mapExtent.intersects(poly.geometery) {
        featuresOnScreen.push(poly);
    } 
}
```

*Edit:* OpenLayers will not help you find the AREA of overlap, as it has no function for determining the geometry of intersection, only wether or not there is an intersection.

In this case you might explore [JSTS Topology Suite](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts).  This client-side library does have an `intersection` function that returns the geometry of the intersecting area.

[Here is an example of JSTS integrated with OpenLayers](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL210/JSTS_Example/jsts_example.asp).

Comment: I can just use the built-in `.onScreen()`, but that's not the point. I need to know **how much area** the visible parts of the polygons take up in the viewport.

Comment: oh.  OpenLayers does not perform this operation.  updating answer with additional information...

Comment: Thanks, I already checked jsts and it can definately intersect etc. But I still hope for a different solution, that only approximates the area, so I can avoid heavy computation.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the centroids not being a great proxy. I ran the following Postgis query on a country borders dataset,

```
select name from countries where st_intersects(geom, st_centroid(geom))='f' order by st_area(geom) desc;
```

and no less than 49 countries out of the 246 in the dataset had centroids outside of the bounds of the country, of which, the first few, sorted by descending order or area were: Indonesia, Somalia, Japan, United Kingdom, Vietnam, Malaysia, Philippines. Having said that, several of these are islands groups which makes it likely that the centroid will fall in the sea, even if the fits reasonably neatly into the bounding box, as is the case with Indonesia.

One approximation that springs to mind would be to divide each country into 4 segments, based on the bounding box and the centroid, ie, NW, NW, SW and SE blocks and calculate the percentage of the country in each block and it's location and store this client side in a dictionary. Then you could check if any of the corner points for the bounding box of a country were in the viewport (a cheap calculation), calculate what percentage of each box was in view using the centroid and each corner point and come up with a weighted average.

I haven't tried this, but it is the best, cheap solution I can think of, if you want to avoid the overhead of JSTS calculations, which presumably would involve storing country boundaries client side. It is clearly not exact, but would be fast, and have minimal storage overhead, which is what you asked for.